# Node.js crypto.pbkdf2

Tags: node.js

I wrote a node.js code using crypto.pbkdf2, but variable `hash` at (2) does not store the value properly so that return value is not normal.

My console log was shown below:

> (2) undefined (1)
>   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

My code is here:

```
function isPasswordCorrect(savedHash, savedSalt, savedIterations, passwordAttempt) {
    var hash;
    crypto.pbkdf2(passwordAttempt, savedSalt, savedIterations, 256, 'sha256', function (err, key) {
        if (err) throw err;
        hash = key.toString('hex');
        console.log("(1) "+hash);
    });
    console.log("(2) "+hash);
    return savedHash == hash;
}
```

Would you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Did you expect a 256-byte result from `crypto.pbkdf2`? In general that is longer than usual. It is also a good idea to save the salt and iteration count with the hash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Yep, noting "(2)" printed before "(1)".

Answer (score 3):

Crypto.pbkdf2 is an async function thus when 2 logs it is before the callback for Cypto.pbkdf2 has executed and set the variable hash to the hash. This is the expected outcome for the code you posted.

```
function isPasswordCorrect(savedHash, savedSalt, savedIterations, 
passwordAttempt) {
var hash;
crypto.pbkdf2(passwordAttempt, savedSalt, savedIterations, 256, 'sha256', function (err, key) {
     /// this is the callback, it happens when cypto is done, it is non blocking
    if (err) throw err;
    hash = key.toString('hex');
    console.log("(1) "+hash);
});
// this happens before the callback... 
console.log("(2) "+hash);
return savedHash == hash;
}
```

You're going to want to pass a callback within the arguments of your isPasswordCorrect function to take the value returned to crypto.pbkdf2

```
function isPasswordCorrect(savedHash, savedSalt, savedIterations, 
  passwordAttempt, callback) {
    crypto.pbkdf2(passwordAttempt, savedSalt, savedIterations, 
    256,'sha256', callback);
}
```

In the callback you will handle err and key.